# philips-hue credentials works on Philips Hue dev website, but fails on Philips Hue iPhone App

Tags: iphone, philips-hue

I am using user name/password to login to developers.meethue.com, and works fine. When I use the same username/password to login on Philips Hue iPhone App, it rejects my login/password.

I have spell checked it and there is no mistake. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The [developers meethue](http://www.developers.meethue.com) website is for 3rd party Hue developers who wish to program apps for Hue.  Login is required to take part in the developers forum and for detailed Hue API documentation.  It has nothing to do with the portal account required for remotely controlling your Hue Bridge.   You need to create a Portal Account for this, either via the Philips app or via the consumer site [meethue](http://www.meethue.com/)  (Follow the My Hue link, top right of the page).